# Lotto function with R

Tags: r, simulation

I just generated 10 random lotto numbers from 1 to 39, now I want to check if these numbers match my winning ticket for example  `w<-c(2,8,19,23,25,32,37)` so that if I have 3 matches in particular combination the prize is 10$ for 4 50$ for 5 100$ for 6 2000$ and for all 7 100000$.

```
    set.seed(99)
    y <- replicate(10,sample(1:39,7,replace=FALSE))
    dimnames(y) <- list(rownames(y,do.NULL=FALSE,prefix=""),
                        colnames(y,do.NULL=FALSE,prefix="Combination"))
    m <- t(y)
    (m2 <- t(apply(m,1,sort)))

                   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
    Combination1     5   19   23   26   33   36   39
    Combination2     7   12   14   18   20   22   37
    Combination3     4    7    8   14   25   27   36
    Combination4     1    4   13   22   27   28   32
    Combination5     1    2    8   12   13   19   37
    Combination6    16   18   22   27   30   31   35
    Combination7    13   15   18   20   31   34   36
    Combination8     5   10   27   28   29   31   35
    Combination9     4   10   14   21   23   33   35
    Combination10    1   17   20   28   29   32   33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `is.element` function. is.element gives you for each element of `w` a boolean telling if this element is part of `m2[1,]`. Then you can sum the vector of booleans given by `is.element`. This sum gives you what you are looking for: the number of elements of `w` that belong to `m2[1,]`.

```
sum( is.element(w,m2[1,]) )
```

As you are repeating the action on each row of `m2`, the `is.element` function must be combined with a for loop or with the `apply` function.

```
colSums(apply(m2, 1, is.element, el=w))
```

**PS**: it also works for `m` and `y`: `colSums(apply(m, 1, is.element, el=w))` and `colSums(apply(y, 2, is.element, el=w))`

Answer (score 5):

The answers received are both correct. I'd just point out that `%in%` and `is.element` are basically the same function. However, there is no need of any `apply`. Keep in mind that `apply` just hides a `for` loop and is very slow compared to vectorized internal R functions. I'd just suggest:

```
  rowSums(matrix(m %in% w, ncol=ncol(m)))
```

which can be way faster:

```
  m<-t(replicate(100000,sample(39,7)))
  system.time(res<-apply(m,1,function(x) sum(x%in%w)))
  #  user  system elapsed 
  # 0.584   0.000   0.587
  system.time(res2<-rowSums(matrix(m %in% w, ncol=ncol(m))))
  #  user  system elapsed 
  # 0.036   0.004   0.040 
  all.equal(res,res2)
  #[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%in%` to get a logical vector of the matches and sum this.

```
apply(m2,1,function(x) sum(x%in%w))
 Combination1  Combination2  Combination3  Combination4  Combination5 
            2             1             2             1             4 
 Combination6  Combination7  Combination8  Combination9 Combination10 
            0             0             0             1             1
```

And for the prize amounts:

```
c("0$","0$","0$","10$","50$","100$","2000$","100000$")[apply(m2,1,function(x) sum(x%in%w))+1]
 [1] "0$"  "0$"  "0$"  "0$"  "50$" "0$"  "0$"  "0$"  "0$"  "0$"
```

Don't retire just yet.